# Replace strip labels with list of values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some data which needs to be labelled with LaTeX expressions, see this small reproducible example. I have a separate list which contains the LaTeX labels for treatment1 and treatment2, to avoid changing the underlying data:

```
## Required packages
library(tidyverse)
library(latex2exp)

## LaTeX labels
labs <- list(treatment1 = c(unname(TeX("$\\textit{Avo}cado$")), unname(TeX("$Ban_{ana}")) ),
             treatment2 = c(unname(TeX("$\\textit{C}at$")), unname(TeX("$D_{og}$")) )  )

## Dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(treatment1 = factor(c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5))),
                 treatment2 = factor(c(rep(c("C", "D"), 5))),
                 var1 = c(1, 4, 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7),
                 var2 = c(2, 8, 11, 13, 4, 10, 11, 2, 6, 10))
```

To apply the LaTeX labels to treatment2, the colour variable, I use the label argument in `scale_colour_manual()`:

```
## Scatter plot with colour varying by treatment2
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = treatment2)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Black", "Blue"),
                      labels = labs$treatment2)

## Add facet by treatment1
p + facet_grid(treatment1 ~ .)
```

[image: ggplot scatter plot with facets]

I've tried using the labeller argument in `facet_grid()` but both of these options result in an error:

```
p + facet_grid(treatment1 ~ ., labeller = labs$treatment1)
p + facet_grid(treatment1 ~ ., labeller = label_value(labs$treatment1))

## > Error in cbind(labels = list(), list(`{`, if (!is.null(.rows) || !is.null(.cols)) { : 
##  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

While trying to use the `as_labeller()` function loads the plot, but with no change to the facet labels:

```
p + facet_grid(treatment1 ~ ., labeller = as_labeller(labs$treatment1))
```

I have also tried to change the labels manually (although I would prefer to refer to a separate object due to the size of my actual data frame), which has no observable effect:

```
p + facet_grid(treatment1 ~ ., 
labeller = labeller(treatment1 = c("A" = unname(TeX("$\\textit{Avo}cado$")),
                                   "B" = unname(TeX("$Ban_{ana}")))))
```

I assume I have to write a new labeller function but I don't really know where to begin. Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
flabels <- function(level){
  labels <- c(
    A = unname(TeX("$\\textit{Avo}cado$")), 
    B = unname(TeX("$Ban_{ana}"))
  )
  labels[level]
}

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = treatment2)) +
  geom_point() 
p + facet_grid(treatment1 ~ ., 
               labeller = labeller(treatment1 = as_labeller(flabels, default = label_parsed)))
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you - is there a way of making the function work if the original factor names have spaces in them? Or would it be necessary to recode the factors?

Comment: @LucyWheeler You mean a space in the level names (here `"A"` and `"B"`) ?

Comment: Yes, so for example if they were `"A E"` and `"B F"` in the data frame.

Comment: @LucyWheeler You can do `c("A E" = unname(......), "B F" = ......)`.